# Pathauto generating odd results

Tags: commerce, path-aliases

I attempted to create a pattern using Drupal Commerce 2 categories and product title.

```
[commerce_product:field_categories:1]/products/[commerce_product:title]
```

When I generate the url alias I get http://localhost:8080/diagnostics-systems/products-18.

When I generate with the pattern:

```
/products/[commerce_product:title]
```

it all comes out correct.

I set the maximum url characters generated to 255 but these done seem to even coming close. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the same happen with a different entity?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I am only using it to bulk generate the product urls